# Generic Repository Insert Multiple Records

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I have managed a generic repository. When I'm inserting one record in table it works. If I want to upload many images and save their path to database, which means I can have 1 to n records, than it is a problem.

**I'm getting error :**

> SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in
>   table 'ItemImages' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

And only first record is saved other n records are not saved into database.

**Here is repository class:**

```cs
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private DbSet<T> entities;

    public Repository(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        entities = _context.Set<T>();
    }
    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        if (entity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Entity");
        }
        entities.Remove(entity);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }

    public T Get(int id)
    {
        return entities.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id == id);
    }

    public T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return entities.Where(predicate).SingleOrDefault();
    }

    public T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, string[] includes)
    {
        return includes
                .Aggregate(entities.AsQueryable(), (query, path) => query.Include(path))
                .Where(predicate)
                .SingleOrDefault();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return entities.ToList();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll(string[] includes)
    {
        return includes.Aggregate(entities.AsQueryable(), (query, path) => query.Include(path));
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return entities.Where(predicate).ToList();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, string[] includes)
    {
        return includes
                .Aggregate(entities.AsQueryable(), (query, path) => query.Include(path))
                .Where(predicate)
                .ToList();
    }

    public void Insert(T entity)
    {
        if (entity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Entity");
        }
        entities.Add(entity);
    }

    public async Task<bool> SaveChangesAsync()
    {

        return (await _context.SaveChangesAsync() > 0);

    }

    public void Update(T entity)
    {

        entities.Update(entity);
    }
```

**Here is code from where I want to insert records:**

```cs
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromForm] ItemImageViewModel viewModel, List<IFormFile> files)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var newItemImage = Mapper.Map<ItemImage>(viewModel);

                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    var filePath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnviroment.WebRootPath + "\\images", file.FileName);
                    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                    {

                        await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                        newItemImage.Name = "\\images\\" + file.FileName;
                        newItemImage.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
                    }
                    _repository.Insert(newItemImage);
                    await _repository.SaveChangesAsync();
                }

            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

ItemImage class

```cs
public class ItemImage : BaseEntity
    {
        [ForeignKey("ItemId")]
        public virtual Item Item { get; set; }

        public int ItemId { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class BaseEntity
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }


        public DateTime? UpdateDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [StringLength(4096)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public string UserId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Because you are saving the data asynchronously inside the foreach. Put the savechange after the `for`

Comment: Then it will save only last record.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your insert & check if your entities is not overwrite at each insert call

Comment: yes, it is trying to overwrite, but why  if table has identity ?

Comment: This is because your are trying to add a value to a column where the database automatically assigns it. So you have an issue with your database model. If you use code first, edit your post to add `ÌtemImage` class

Comment: I put my code for database, what is wrong with that ?

Comment: For me nothing. You DTO seems to be correct...

Comment: I don't know what to tell, good or bad, since problem still is present... Any other idea ?

Comment: The issue here is you are initializing `newItemImage` only once which is outside for loop. So for the first time it will be saved properly. In next iteration it will have `Id` property set and you just change the Name and CreatedDate and try to insert it again. Because it already has `Id` set the db is throwing this error back. You might want to put `var newItemImage = Mapper.Map<ItemImage>(viewModel);` inside the loop before `var filePath...` line.

Comment: I really missed that. That is correct answer :)